# automatic daily email sending script in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can somebody guide me to write a code in ruby on rails which send daily automatic email to clients who are registered.please i am new in ruby on rails. Links or source code is needed which will clearly me that how i can write script to send automatic email.

Answer (score 4):

On how to send emails you can look into the rails guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

You can also see this screencast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

To automate a task to run every day, I would advise using the whenever gem, which is a pretty interface for cron:

https://github.com/javan/whenever

Also, look at this screencast which is a nice introduction to cron and the whenever gem:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks.i am going to try these links hope so it will clear all about email sending